# System tests with ruby (rspec maybe)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Is there any way to do system testing with ruby?

I'm trying to test a multithreaded service (distributed in warbled in jar file) with having just SOAP inputs and STDOUT as outputs, and that's all what I have. I need to create custom, not trivial scenarios, and looking for the best way to do that. Google does not help with that.

> **System testing** of software or hardware is testing conducted on a complete, integrated system to evaluate the system's compliance with its specified requirements. System testing falls within the scope of **black box testing**, and as such, should require no knowledge of the inner design of the code or logic.

**UPDATE**:
 I suppose I had to say that I have 3 separate components with interaction between them. And this service, im talking about is like proxy for other 2. And if I just start to write code, I need to repeat lots of functionality. So yes I'm looking for some framework to mock both services and ability to create multiple of scenarios.

Comment: Any (reasonable) language can send SOAP requests and read stdout.  Are you looking for a framework to build them in?  Libraries to help you?  What have you tried that didn't work for you?

Comment: @NickVeys yes, some framework, to have an ability to create mocks and keep code DRY, not repeating a functionality of other components. take a look at update

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ruby is excellent for system or application level tests.

I would recommend [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/).  Cucumber is a Ruby application which lets you define an external DSL (Domain Specific Language) specific to your environment, and then use that DSL to write and run tests.

Here's the example Cucumber test (from the Cucumber home page):

```
Feature: Addition
  In order to avoid silly mistakes
  As a math idiot
  I want to be told the sum of two numbers

  Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

That's written in the mini-language you define.  These "step definitions" are in Ruby, using Cucumber's internal DSL:

```
Given /I have entered (.*) into the calculator/ do |n|
  calculator = calculator.new
  calculator.push(n.to_i)
end
```

These step definitions are what tie your custom external DSL to the code or system under test.  This example tests a simple Ruby class, but Cucumber is fine for integrated testing of libraries or applications.

Keeping [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is not a problem.  Step definitions can call other step definitions, and since they are written in Ruby, you can easily put shared code into modules or classes for use by your step definitions.

All that's left to answer is whether Ruby and its available libraries have the capabilities needed to drive your test environment.  Ruby is a good "glue" language, able to easily run other programs.  It also has a fairly good set of libraries (called "Ruby gems") available, including several which can do soap (e.g. [savon](http://savonrb.com/)).  Libraries are available for working with XML and interfacing with various protocols (HTTP, FTP, etc.).